# Build failure: cannot download mule-extensions-3.8.3.pom unauthorized

Tags: maven, build, unauthorized

I have problem with credentials to the repository-master.mulesoft.org
Could you help me?

```
[INFO] Building Mule connector-salesforce Application 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------     ---
[INFO] Downloading: https://repository-    master.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases- ee/org/mule/extensions/mule-extensions/3.8.3/mule-extensions-3.8.3.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 23.892 s
```

Comment: Sounds like you have Internet issues, or are behind a proxy? What is your Maven settings?

Answer (score 0):

download this to your local repository

https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/mule/extensions/mule-extensions/3.8.3-SNAPSHOT/mule-extensions-3.8.3-20161125.034027-63.pom

under
[user].m2\repository\org\mule\extensions\mule-extensions\3.8.3

Comment: This does not work. You need to have the license first before you can download from repository-master mulesoft.